# Converting Lat Lon in WGS84 format to UK NGR in QGIS

Tags: qgis, wgs84

I have csv file that has WGS Lat/Lon, what I need to do is convert these to UK NGR i.e Easting/Northing.
In QGIS there under Field Calculator I think there are some defined operator like `$X` and `$Y` that does this but I can't make it work.

Comment: You need to combine `$x` and `$y` with `transform`.

Comment: hi Erik,can you clarify the code that need to be used in field calculator for transform?

Comment: x(transform(make_point(your_lon, your_lat), 4326, 27700)) would be the x coordinate

Comment: load file, export as a geopackage (or shapefile) with SRS set to EPSG:27700 and then use for what ever you need

Comment: thanks All for comments, it worked